# How can I set different colors in a ZedGraph histogram?

Tags: c#, colors, zedgraph

I got a histogram drawn in ZedGraph. And I have to set the specific color for a specific range of the values. For example:

```
Graph Pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;    
list = new PointPairList ();    
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{    
    list.Add(i, array_with_y_values[i]);    
}    
Pane.AddBar("", list, Color.Red);
```

And how I can set the other color for some of them?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want a single bar with multiple colors? Or you want to add a new bar of a different color?

Comment: Sorry, I want a single bar with different color. I tried to add new bar instead of the old one but it overlays on it. It should look like solid red then solid yellow(for example) and solid red again without any gradients and other freaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? This piece of code adds 50 bars with random y values between 0 and 15. It will color bars with y values <5 as red, 5-10 as yellow, and >10 as green.

```
GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    list.Add(i, rand.Next(15));
}

BarItem myBar = pane.AddBar("", list, Color.Red);
Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green };
myBar.Bar.Fill = new Fill(colors);
myBar.Bar.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByY;
myBar.Bar.Fill.RangeMin = 5;
myBar.Bar.Fill.RangeMax = 10;

zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
```

This is a modified example of the ZedGraph one here: http://www.zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Multi-Colored_Bar_Demo

Comment: The link to zedgraph.org is (effectively) broken now.