# Zedgraph Horizontal Bar graph with different bar colors C#

Tags: c#, colors, zedgraph

I am working on zedgraph and generating a horizontal bar graph. I only want to know if there is any way by which each single bar can be made of different color. The output of the code is acceptable, I only intend on changing the color of the bars being generated. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Nominees";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Votes";

        // Make up some random data points

        string[] labels= new string[count];

        for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            labels[counter] = voternames[i];
            counter++;
        }



        for (int i = count1-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            y0[counter1] = Convert.ToDouble(votes[i]);
            counter1++;
        }


        // Generate a red bar with "Curve 1" in the legend
        BarItem myBar = myPane.AddBar("", y0, null, Color.Green);


        // Draw the X tics between the labels instead of 
        // at the labels
        myPane.YAxis.MajorTic.IsBetweenLabels = false;
        // Set the XAxis labels
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels;
        // Set the XAxis to Text type
        myPane.YAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;

        myPane.BarSettings.Base = BarBase.Y;

        // Fill the Axis and Pane backgrounds
        myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 255));

        // Tell ZedGraph to refigure the
        // axes since the data have changed

        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Refresh();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set different colors in a ZedGraph histogram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461554/how-can-i-set-different-colors-in-a-zedgraph-histogram)

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for, the original link to source is:
http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Multi-colored_Bar_Chart_with_ZedGraph. The main modification was making a Point pair list instead of sending the double array for creating bars, giving reference to color array and setting min and max range for fills. The modified code is as follows:

```
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Nominees";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Votes";

        // Make up some random data points

        string[] labels= new string[count];
        //string[] labelx = new string[count];
        for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            labels[counter] = voternames[i];
            counter++;
        }



        for (int i = count1-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            y0[counter1] = Convert.ToDouble(votes[i]);
            counter1++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < y0.Length; i++)
        {
    //Adding the x axis data and using y axis as a source to color a single bar
            list.Add(y0[i], i / 2.0);
        }


        Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Purple};

    // Generate a bar with point pair list in the legend
        BarItem myBar = myPane.AddBar("", list, Color.Green);

    // Giving ref of color array
    myBar.Bar.Fill = new Fill(colors);

    //Setting to fill with using point values of y axis
        myBar.Bar.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByY;

    //Setting min and max range is important
        myBar.Bar.Fill.RangeMin = 0;
        myBar.Bar.Fill.RangeMax = Convert.ToInt32(y0[0]);

        // Draw the X tics between the labels instead of 
        // at the labels
        myPane.YAxis.MajorTic.IsBetweenLabels = false;
        // Set the XAxis labels
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.TextLabels = labels;
        // Set the XAxis to Text type
        myPane.YAxis.Type = AxisType.Text;

        myPane.BarSettings.Base = BarBase.Y;

        // Fill the Axis and Pane backgrounds
        //myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White,Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 166), 90F);
        myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 255));

        // Tell ZedGraph to refigure the
        // axes since the data have changed

        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Refresh();
```